# GPS tracking system?

Tags: android, android-service

I have to create a service which tracks the GPS location of the user even when the application is killed until when i stop the service. Is it possible?
I have created a service which makes use of LocationListener and also made use of socket.io which communicates with server. But when the application is paused the location updates donot reflect and when i kill the application the socket closes. Please suggest a proper way to implement.

[Link to the service i have created](https://github.com/Anurag690/gpstracker/blob/master/TrackingService.java)

Comment: It is possible, but on android 8 you need to show notification all the time until your service stopped.

Comment: i have created a notification using startForegound, even then the service gets killed. @VadimEksler

Comment: So show your code.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/Anurag690/gpstracker) @VadimEksler please look into this Service in here

Comment: anyone? there is a link to my service above. please check and help.

Comment: Try to start your notification in `onStartCommand` , use NotificationChannel for your notification.

Comment: @VadimEksler notification channel is used when if targetSdkVersion is above 26 but mine is 23 and putting it in onStartCommand didnt helped. Also i am already able to create the notification with the help of startForeground, when i am killing my app the notification goes away so as the service. Any other help?

Comment: everything is working fine in my emulator(nexus api level 25) but not in my mobile which is mi note 3 with android version of 6.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is my `onStartCommand`

```
 h = new Handler();
 r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startSomeJob();
                    startForeground(101, updateNotification(0));
                }
            };

 h.post(r);
```

And here is notification:

```
private Notification updateNotification(int progress) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(action), 0);

        String info = progress + "%";

        NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) if (mNotifyManager != null) {
            createChannel(mNotifyManager);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "101")
                .setContentTitle(info)
                .setTicker(info)
                .setContentText("Uploading")
                .setVibrate(new long[] {0L})
                .setProgress(100, progress, false)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true);

        return builder.build();
    }
```

And in my someJob if there is some update, it call `startForeground(101, updateNotification(percentDone));`

In your case when location is changed in function `onLocationChanged` you need to call startForeground with notification.